# C# Visual Web Developer: Listing All Files In A Directory As A DropDownList

Tags: c#

I am developing a web page that displays a report.  The report gets updated monthly and I would like the option to display the previous reports as well as the current one.  I don't even know where to begin with this and I am hoping for suggestions.  All I can think of off the top of my head is to somehow display all of the reports in the directory in a DropDownList (if that's possible).

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Are you asking how can it do it from a c# side or more of a user experience design side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) method to get the list of files in your directory.

You can then use this list as a datasource for your DropDownList control

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles("path to your dir");
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = fileList;
ddl.DataBind();
```